# How to install docker-compose v2 in Mac Ventura?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I have the below docker desktop installed in Mac Ventura 13.0.1 (M1 Pro chip).

- Version 4.5.0
- Engine 20.10.12
- Compose 1.29.2
- Kubernetes 1.22.5

Can someone let me know how can I upgrade `compose` to version 2.6.0 or above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been answered in [docker community forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-install-docker-compose-v2-in-mac-ventura/133217). Cross-posting the answer below :-

> You can download the version for the ARM based CPU (aarch64) on macOS
> (darwin). Note that if you just download it from the browser, macOS
> will not let you run it, because it will remember that the file was
> downloaded using the browser (or maybe because I used Google Chrome, I
> am not sure) and macOS could not check the author of the binary. So I
> downloaded from command line using curl.
>
> ```
> https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.14.2/docker-compose-darwin-aarch64
> ```
>
> Since (in the previous topic) you used `docker-compose` instead of
> `docker compose`, you need to know that Docker Compose v2 is a plugin
> of Docker and plugins can be installed to multiple locations. When you
> run `docker-compose` you will run `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` but
> your plugins can be in your home as well:
>
> ```
> $HOME/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
> ```
>
> So when you run `docker compose` where `compose` is an argument of
> `docker`, docker will execute the plugin in th cli-plugins folder if
> `docker-compose` is there.
>
> Since Docker Desktop has Docker Compsoe 2.13.0 at the moment which is
> good enough for you to fix the issue discussed in the [other
> topic](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-displaying-all-services-not-the-one-defined-in-docker-compose-yml/133157/3), I would not upgrade it at all, unless you need a feature in
> the latest version. If you still want to upgarde, you could just
> install the plugin and leave `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose`
> untouched.
>
> **update**
>
> Okay, I was confused because you mentioned a newer version number in
> the other topic used on AWS and here you mentioned 1.29 on macOS.
> macOS has Docker Compose v2 and you can optionally allow Docker
> Desktop to change `docker-compose` to point to Docker Compose v2. So
> the process I shared is still the way to download a specific compose
> version, but you don’t need that on macOS. Just use the `docker compose` command instead of `docker-compose`